# jQuery: Remove html tags from all instances of DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple instances of `.text-excerpt` in my HTML page, I would like to know how I can strip all tags from each instance of the element.

HTML:

```
<span class="text-excerpt">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing <br>elit. Aenean eget.</p>
</span>
<span class="text-excerpt">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing <br>elit. Aenean eget.</p>
</span>
<span class="text-excerpt">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing <br>elit. Aenean eget.</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for that. The getter version of `.text()` will grab the `.innerHTML` property of the element and filter out any HTML tags.

Pass a function to the setter version of `.text()` and return the gotten value.

```
$('.text-excerpt').text(function(_,v){
    return v;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t85o4o1/)

---

You *could* make a neat little plugin out of it:

```
$.fn.removeHTML = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).text(function(_, v){ return v ; });
    });
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t85o4o1/1/)